# Exclude all results ending on .html

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to filter out all the files that don't end in `.html`. On top of this they all start with a different date, so only those that match the date pattern.

**Example of file names:**

```
2015-06-23 1003 (Tuesday) - Inconsistencies found.html
2015-06-23 1003 (Tuesday) - Groups without place holder account.txt
2015-06-23 1003 (Tuesday) - Inactive users.csv
2015-06-23 0948 (Tuesday) - Inconsistencies found.html
2015-06-23 0948 (Tuesday) - Description not following the standard.csv
2015-06-23 0948 (Tuesday) - Groups without place holder account.txt
```

**Expected results:**

```
# when $d = 2015-06-23 1003
2015-06-23 1003 (Tuesday) - Groups without place holder account.txt
2015-06-23 1003 (Tuesday) - Inactive users.csv
```

**Current regex:**

```
$RegExAttachments = "^{0:00}-{1:00}-{2:00}\s{3:00}{4:00}\s\({5}\).*\." -f $d.Year,$d.Month,$d.Day,$d.Hour,$d.Minute,$d.DayOfWeek
$Attachments = Get-ChildItem $LogFolder | where {$_.Name -match $RegExAttachments} | foreach {$_.FullName}
$Attachments
```

The current regex brings up the correct results, however, it also contains the file ending in HTML which I would like to avoid in the result. I've also tried `"^{0:00}-{1:00}-{2:00}\s{3:00}{4:00}\s\({5}\).*\.[^html]"` but then it doesn't bring up the `txt files` either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a regex for more than you have to. Powershell has enough built in capabilities for filtering on something as trivial as a file extension.

Use:

```
$Attachments = Get-ChildItem $LogFolder | where {($_.extension -ne '.html') -and ($_.Name -match $RegExAttachments)}
```

Characters inside `[]` in a regex are not a literal string - `[^html]` means don't match `h`, `t`, `m` or `l`, no matter what the order. So it doesn't match `txt` because that character class contains a `t`

Answer (score 0):

you can also use below

```
Get-ChildItem $LogFolder|where {$_.extension -ne ".html"} |where {$_.Name -match $RegExAttachments}
```